# Position divs from the bottom to the top

Tags: css, html

I want to create a tabbed pane in which the tabs are ordered this way:

```
----------------------------------
-tab6 | tab7                     -
-tab1 | tab2 | tab3 | tab4 | tab5-
----------------------------------
```

Setting `tab1` on the bottom left is position is no problem, but when the line wraps, `tab6` and `tab7` are at the bottom like this:

```
----------------------------------    
-tab1 | tab2 | tab3 | tab4 | tab5-
-tab6 | tab7                     -
----------------------------------
```

Is there a way to change that "read order"?

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="nav_tabs">
        <div class="tab">test1</div>
        <div class="tab">test2</div>
        <div class="tab">test3</div>
        <div class="tab">test4</div>
        <div class="tab">test5</div>
        <div class="tab">test6</div>
        <div class="tab">test7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#header {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#nav_tabs {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}

.tab {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

Here is what looks like now: http://jsfiddle.net/qpHNN/336/

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Probably a script will be necessary.

Comment: Added jsfiddle, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, IMO there's probably no way to reorder these elements to flow them from *bottom* to *top*.

However, you could fake the effect by using [`transform: rotate(180deg)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) for the `#nav_tabs` element (the container) and negate the rotate effect for each `.tab` by `rotate(-180deg)`, as follows:

```css
#nav_tabs {
    /* other styles... */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.tab {
    /* other styles... */
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    float: right;  /* in this case you need to float the elements contrariwise */
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/qpHNN/337/)**.